# Credentials for Powershell Azure management cmdlets

Tags: powershell, azure, azure-sql-database, azure-powershell

What are the options to authenticate the powershell azure management cmdlets like `New-AzureSqlDatabaseServer` and `New-AzureSqlDatabase`?

It looks like `New-AzureSqlDatabaseServer` needs the administrator's user name and password explicitly passed whereas `New-AzureSqlDatabase` needs to know the context (Context can be created using `Get-Credential` cmdlet or by manually creating an object of type `PSCredential` by passing plain text password)

Wondering if there are other ways to authenticate these management cmdlets without passing/prompting for the admin user name or password? I am looking for something in the lines of publish settings certificate that could be imported once to the deployment servers.

**Background** - I am looking to automate the SQL azure server and database creation using powershell and trying to do this without having to prompt/pass admin password

Answer (score 1):

So, `New-AzureSqlDatabaseServer` uses your subscription credentials.  You can currently create a context for use with `New-AzureSqlDatabase` using a `PSCredential`, which you can create by instantiating a `SecureString` for the password - the `ConvertTo-SecureString` commandlet can help with this.

Answer (score 0):

I was looking for the same thing and I found a trick to get it...

```
$cred=Get-Credential
$userName=$cred.UserName
$password=$cred.GetNetworkCredential().Password
New-AzureSqlDatabaseServer -Version "12.0" -AdministratorLogin $userName -AdministratorLoginPassword $password -Location "West US"
```

Reference: [Decrypt PowerShell Secure String Password](http://blogs.technet.com/b/heyscriptingguy/archive/2013/03/26/decrypt-powershell-secure-string-password.aspx/%22Decrypt%20PowerShell%20Secure%20String%20Password%22)

Comment: When I call Get-Credential, I get prompted for my credentials.  I think infinity didn't want to get prompted for credentials.

Comment: Well, I doubt there is a way to get the password without first entering it! That would be very insecure.   ;-)